# how would create an alarm manager with reciever to put phone on silent at certain time?

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I have been trying this for a while and i cannot figure out the best way to do it and i do not really understand what teh broadcast reciever does. what i would like is for the alarm to be fired and maybe an activity to put the phone on silent.

thanks in advance

Comment: wow I wish I had something like that while I was in school

Answer (score 0):

Use the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)'s setRepeating method to run your task periodically. To change the ringer you can use the [AudioManger](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html)'s setRingerMode method.

Answer (score 0):

This is working code. It wakes CPU every 10 minutes and shows notification.

Add to Manifest.xml:

```
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
...
<receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name="Alarm"></receiver>
...
```

Code:

```
public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver 
{    
     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
     {   
         PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
         PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "YOUR TAG");
         wl.acquire();

         // Put here YOUR code.
         Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm !!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // For example

         wl.release();
     }

     public void SetAlarm(Context context)
     {
         AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
         PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
         am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 10, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
     }

     public void CancelAlarm(Context context)
     {
         Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
         PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
         AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         alarmManager.cancel(sender);
     }
}
```